# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str' tkinter error

Tags: python, string, tkinter, python-3.5, nonetype

I have a problem with this code as I keep geting a syntax error. I created a list with different greetings but I couldn't get it to recall on the line 24. Please Help. Thanks :)

```
import pyttsx
import sklearn
import random

speech_engine = pyttsx.init('sapi5') # see      http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx.init
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
def  Hello():

    words = [line.strip() for line in open('Hello.txt')]
    speak(random.choice(words))




def speak(text):
    speech_engine.say(text)
speech_engine.runAndWait()


intro=(Hello())

Greeting=input(speak("What is your name"))

Account=input(speak(intro + Greeting + ", Would you like to Log in or create an account"))


if Account==("Create An Account") or Account==("Create An Account") or Account==("create an account"):
        Password=input(speak("What is the password going to be for your account"))
        text_file = open("Password.txt", "a")
        text_file.write("|          "+ Greeting +"                 |          "+ Password +"          |\n")
        text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your function `Hello()` does not `return` anything, it implicitly returns `None`, so intro = None. Now you try to "add" a string to None, which is exactly, what your error message states.

If you just want to call your `Hello()` function to greet the user, simply do so by calling `Hello()` without assigning the return value. Since it is `None` anyways, there is no obvious reason to include it in the `input(...)` statement.

EDIT:

Taking your comment into account, I suggest you change your function:

```
def Hello():
    words = [line.strip() for line in open('Hello.txt')]
    return random.choice(words)
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix this? Sorry I'm fairly new to this

Comment: Depends on what you try to achieve with `intro + Greeting + "..."`. Right now removing the `intro +` part could fix that specific problem.

Comment: I would but that is the part I need so it doesn't say "Hello" everytime.

Comment: Right now you would "speak" a random hello-statement every time the `Hello()` function is called. Then you try to speak the account creation-question. I think it would be better to have the `Hello()` function return a random greeting, that then can be used in the `speak()` function below.